# How can I decrypt encrypted RSA message in C++ (Encrypting in python, Decrypting in C++)

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa

I have encrypted a message in Python:

```py
import base64
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5

key = """-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
SOME_SECURE_KEY
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"""

private_key = RSA.import_key(key)
cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(private_key)
print(base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(b"SECRET MESSAGE")).decode())
```

And I want to decrypt it in C++ using OpenSSL.
How can I do that ?

```cpp
int main() {
    std::string privateKey = "MY-KEY";
    BIO *bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(privateKey.c_str(), privateKey.length()); // -1: assume string is null terminated
    RSA *rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(bio, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    BIO_free(bio);


    auto vec = a_function_that_decodes_base64(my_cipher_text);
    unsigned char arr[vec.size()];
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), arr);

    unsigned char decrypted[4098] = {};
    int decrypt_len = RSA_private_decrypt(RSA_size(rsa),
                                            arr, decrypted, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);

    if (decrypt_len == -1) {
        char *err = ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL);
        std::cout << err << std::endl;
    }

    RSA_free(rsa);
}
```

I have tried this code but it doesn't works and I got error that says incorrect padding

Edit: also I thought it's better to also share base64 decoding function, maybe it has bugs:

```cpp
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
std::vector<BYTE> bbase64_decode(std::string const& encoded_string) {
    int in_len = encoded_string.size();
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int in_ = 0;
    BYTE char_array_4[4], char_array_3[3];
    std::vector<BYTE> ret;

    while (in_len-- && ( encoded_string[in_] != '=') && is_base64(encoded_string[in_])) {
        char_array_4[i++] = encoded_string[in_]; in_++;
        if (i ==4) {
            for (i = 0; i <4; i++)
                char_array_4[i] = base64Mapping.find(char_array_4[i]);

            char_array_3[0] = (char_array_4[0] << 2) + ((char_array_4[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
            char_array_3[1] = ((char_array_4[1] & 0xf) << 4) + ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3c) >> 2);
            char_array_3[2] = ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3) << 6) + char_array_4[3];

            for (i = 0; (i < 3); i++)
                ret.push_back(char_array_3[i]);
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    if (i) {
        for (j = i; j <4; j++)
            char_array_4[j] = 0;

        for (j = 0; j <4; j++)
            char_array_4[j] = base64Mapping.find(char_array_4[j]);

        char_array_3[0] = (char_array_4[0] << 2) + ((char_array_4[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
        char_array_3[1] = ((char_array_4[1] & 0xf) << 4) + ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3c) >> 2);
        char_array_3[2] = ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3) << 6) + char_array_4[3];

        for (j = 0; (j < i - 1); j++) ret.push_back(char_array_3[j]);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

I think there is nothing to add to this question anymore.
But stack overflow says I should add more detail and this is the reason that I'vr wrote these two last sentences (:

Comment: Why not just use openssl's base64 coder/decoder? https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/BIO_f_base64.html. Although having a bigger-than-necessary buffer is not a problem, it does appear that you are confusing bits and bytes. A 4096-**bit** RSA key is 256 bytes, but `RSA_size()` gives the result in bits.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk thanks for your answer, I'll try openssl's b64 decoder. but where did I made mistake about rsa key ?

Comment: *but where did I made mistake about rsa key ?* Where is the only place in your code where you use `RSA_size()`? Also, Misha T makes a good point that you're trying to encrypt and decrypt with the private key, which doesn't make sense. Be sure to read up on the [basics of RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)).